Kali Linux not showing text in GUI
I have almost no prior experience with Kali Linux, or Linux in general, but I have Kali installed on a virtual machine (UTM SE). However, when it starts, it loads the GUI, except there is no text. It is just not displaying text. Logging in still works fine though.

Maybe you didn't install any font?

It's just unclear what you mean by "no text". Are the only things you see just some window rectangles without any text?

"I have almost no prior experience with Kali Linux, or Linux in general". Kali Linux is not for beginners  Simply installing Kali does NOT make you a security expert. Use a more general purpose distribution, e.g. Ubuntu to learn with.

I used a cm online before

Whatever you mean by a 'cm', it clearly wasn't sufficient experience. Please try again with an actual distribution meant for general use, not one that's specifically designed as a specialized pentesting tool.
